# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplotp'

Tags: python

See the attached image:

[image]

Hello every one,

Can I get your help, I am using Jupyter notebook and when import the `matplotlib.pyplotp` I get an error.
I have used `pip install matplotlib` in anaconda and it seemed to be already installed :

```
    (base) C:\Users\...>pip install matplotlib
    Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.2.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\shadi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
    Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
    .

.
.
Rdateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.15.0)
```

and I am still getting the same error `: ModuleNotFoundError:` No module named `matplotlib.pyplotp`

Kindly help me

Comment: Does import matplotlib output any errors?

Comment: Try `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, I think it just a typo

Comment: This is exactly what I did,, see the attached image

Comment: i think module name is matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: you enter wrong module name in second line correct it as import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid mistake, I am using kite tool for command auto complete and it adds some extra letters .... Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people in the comments pointed out, you simply have a typo in the import code.

As a side note, please do not post screenshots of code.
Instead copy the code and error message and format them as code in the question itself.
E.G:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplotp as plt
import pandas as pd

----------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-715cc5d20d02> in <module>
    1 import numpy as np
--->2 import matplotlib.pyplotp as plt
    3 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplotp'
```